# Using postgres to check if a file exists

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database that contains a field (VARCHAR) that is the full path and filename of a file on the same server as the database.

I can list the files as so.

```
SELECT myFileName FROM tableA;
```

There's a catch - some of the files don't actually exist (not in their listed location anyway).

I can use pg_stat_file() to list information about any file that exists

```
SELECT myFileName, pg_stat_file(myFileName) FROM tableA;
```

However, if one file referenced in my database doesn't actually exist, then the above query falls over with an appropriate error message

```
ERROR:  could not stat file "?????????????????": No such file or directory.
```

Question - is it possible to write a postgres SQL query to indicate if a file exists or doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html), `pg_stat_file` has optional `missing_ok boolean` argument for exactly such purpose.

> Some of these functions take an optional missing_ok parameter, which specifies the behavior when the file or directory does not exist. If true, the function returns NULL or an empty result set, as appropriate. If false, an error is raised. The default is false.

```
postgres=# select pg_stat_file('/foo');
ERROR:  could not stat file "/foo": No such file or directory
postgres=# select pg_stat_file('/foo', true);
 pg_stat_file 
--------------
 
(1 строка)
```